# How to pre-select radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an edit button for database and onclick of it i am opening a dialogue box with the values of database.

it is working properly for text-box but in radio-button i am getting unknown behavior, can any 1 help?

```
<td valign="top" style="Height: 25px" align="right">
    <span class="Label" ng-model="mainCtrl.edititem.type">Type*</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
<td>
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" class="rad"  value="User" checked="checked"/>
    <span class="Label">User </span>  
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" value="Executable" class="rad"/>
    <span class="Label">Executable</span>
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" value="ProcessMap" class="rad"/>
    <span class="Label">ProcessMap</span>
</td>
```

Comment: @Michael_B thanks, it was just typing mistake,

Comment: why are you checking all the radio boxes?

Comment: @bansi it is just for testing purpose, what i want is it should be pre-selected according to database, if i select only 1 then that perticular will be selected everytime.

Comment: Checkboxes can have multiples with the same name checked, while radio buttons can only have one with the same name checked.

Comment: @Sam i want it should be selected as per database record, it was not happening so i selected all

Comment: You can't have multiple selections when using radios as long as they all have the same `name` property.

Comment: Editted, removed checked for other 2, still not working

Comment: This might need more explanation. At first it sounded like you just wanted to know how to preselect a radio button. You're already doing that with the `checked` attribute. If your goal is to mark something as checked based on information coming from a database, you'll need to use JS for that. Is that what you're asking us for?

Comment: @Sam Yes, my information is coming from database and based on that information i have to select the radiobutton. i used angularjs for rendering the data..

Comment: I'd need to see an example of the data coming from the database. I'd prefer to see the specific database entries that correlate with the User, Executable, and ProcessMap input elements.

Comment: @Chirag please edit your question and add the full problem you want to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code example I assume that the database value you need is stored in `mainCtrl.edititem.type`? That variable is set to "User", "Executable" or "ProcessMap" right?

In that case, you can let angular do the work for you by using the `ng-model` attribute on each radio button. When the model value equals the radio button's `value` attribute it will automatically be checked:

```
<td>
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" value="User" class="rad" ng-model="mainCtrl.edititem.type" />
    <span class="Label">User </span>  
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" value="Executable" class="rad" ng-model="mainCtrl.edititem.type" />
    <span class="Label">Executable</span>
    <input th:type="radio" name="group1" value="ProcessMap" class="rad" ng-model="mainCtrl.edititem.type" />
    <span class="Label">ProcessMap</span>
</td>
```